# Moving text from one <div> to another by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I want to do is this:
[image]

I want to either move all the words on the left `<div>` to the right `<div>` or moving just the selected ones. The part of clicking to highlight the words is already done but moving the content from one `<div>` to the other is something that I've never done before. Is this something that can be done with jquery or javascript?  **[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/sSZgx/1/)**. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "The part of clicking to highlight the words is already done"?

Comment: One task would appear to be much simpler than the other. You should probably share your code for highlighting selected words.

Comment: Can you show us the bit that's already done? Just so we know what to work with?

Comment: I'm guessing it's not actually a textarea because you can't have styled/attributed text in the textarea. Are you using a `contenteditable` div?

Comment: @Sergio What you are seen on the image, you click the words to select or highlight them.

Comment: @Labanino, you cannot have styled/attributed text inside the `<textarea>` and expect to retrive that .value keeping the styled/attributed text... (!)

Comment: @Matt Harrison Yes, it is some kind of multiple selection but the words are next to each other. I just created a div with a fixed height and overflow-y:auto;

Comment: @Labanino This would be much less painful for all if we can see how your existing code works. Otherwise we're shooting in the dark.

Comment: "it is some kind of multiple selection". Huh? "I just created a div" So where's the `<textarea>`??

Comment: I think it's something like this going on: http://jsfiddle.net/MgR7A/

Comment: @MattHarrison Ok, this is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/sSZgx/1/

Comment: @Labanino So using my answer below, you get this: http://jsfiddle.net/sSZgx/2/

Comment: @MattHarrison I want to use this solution one more time on the same page. I got rid of the id's to use class selectors instead for the sake of maintenance but now if I click to pass a selected word or all of them it does the same to the other. What should I do to be able to use it more than ones? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/sSZgx/5/ Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not got much to go off here but I'm guessing the highlighting thing adds a span with a class to that text which is inside a div. So you could do something like this with jQuery:

```
$("body").on("click", "#copySelected", function(){
    var text = "";
    $("div .highlighted").each(function(){
         text += $(this).text();
         $("textarea").val(text);
    })
})

$("body").on("click", "#copyAll", function(){
    $("textarea").val($("div").text());
})
```

You'll obviously need to change the selectors to match your markup.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MgR7A/

Comment: Exactly, this bootstrap, so when you click the word it adds the label class to the selected word

Comment: @Labanino I've added a fiddle.

Comment: Thank you so very much Matt, that was easier than I thought.